# Regex script to fnd matches in two columns

Tags: python, regex

I am working with an exceptionally large amount of data that can be outputted to an excel file or text file (with optional deliminators). They're records from a database that need matching records to be manipulated. Usually this is done manually but I wish to automate the matching process. Essentially there are two columns, one column will have a sequence of numbers (either 9 or 12 depending) the second column will have a last and first name (sometimes middle initial). I want to use a script to automate the matching process for me and output the matches to a text file. Here is a look at how the text file looks:

```
000000000        Smith, John
ABS000000000        Smith, Jane
000000010           SMITH, JANE M
```

So I want to match records in two ways, 1) catch the records with a preceding sequence of upper case letters.
2) match the name (as you can see, there might be an issue as the case is not always the same and sometimes the name is written with a middle initial)
.

So far I've started to write a test script in python. As you can tell i am not too familiar with regex and the re module, so I wish some guidance as to how I can get started with finding the records with a preceding 3 character sequence:

```
import re

source = open('source.txt')
match = open('matches.txt', 'w')

for lines in source:
    m = re.search('(^ABC)', lines)
    if m:
        x = m.group()
        print ('match found: ' + x)
        match.write(x +"\n")

source.close()
match.close()
```

So far it is only writing ABS to the output file, and not the whole ID from the first column.
Secondly I'm also wondering about how to go about tackling the second column, which would imply to mach on a last name bases only, because sometimes the first name will appear with or without a middle initial. But I only want to print a match that is first found by way of a record with a 3 character sequence preceding the ID number. So this might imply a nested if loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally it might be done like this

```
 # ^([A-Z]{3}\d+)\s+([^,\s]+)

 ^                       # Beginning
 ( [A-Z]{3} \d+ )        # (1), Capture group. Three letters, any number of digits
 \s+                     # One or more whitespace (delimiter)
 ( [^,\s]+ )             # (2), Capture group. Last name (up to comma)
```

Output

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 30 , len 25 ) 
ABS000000000        Smith  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 30 , len 12 ) 
ABS000000000  
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 50 , len 5 ) 
Smith
```

Comment: Excellent. I was able to use the regex for the ABS000000000 and 000000000 type ids.